# In symfony, my repository returns one row rather than multiple rows

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, repository, entity

in my Symfony repo, i have this code

```
 /**
 * @param int  $year
 * @param int  $month
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function findByYearMonth(int $year, int $month = 0): array
{

    $B = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
    $B
        ->andWhere('YEAR(b.bookingDate) = :year_data')
        ->setParameter('year_data', $year);

    if (!!$month) {
        $B
            ->andWhere('MONTH(b.bookingDate) = :month_data')
            ->setParameter('month_data', $month);
    }

    $query = $B
        ->orderBy('b.bookingDate', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery();

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

the SQL request is

```
SELECT b0_.booking_date AS booking_date_0, b0_.former_id AS former_id_1, b0_.trader_id AS trader_id_2, b0_.training_id AS training_id_3, b0_.customer AS customer_4, b0_.title AS title_5, b0_.comment AS comment_6 FROM booking_professional b0_ WHERE YEAR(b0_.booking_date) = 2021 AND MONTH(b0_.booking_date) = 9 ORDER BY b0_.booking_date ASC;
```

When i test the SQL request in DB, i have mutliple rows, and when i test my repository one single entity was returned

I don't understand how this can be possible,
have you more ideas to fixed it ?

thanks

Comment: Seems unlikely.  Are you sure the problem is not in how the results are being handled?  Have you tried adding a dump($query->getResult()) directly in the repository method?  Are you certain your application is connecting to the same database you are testing against?

Comment: Hello, yes i've done, but the result is the same, only the first was returned 

Comment: can you show the code that contains the first result only? how did u debug?

Comment: Remove all the where conditions and just dump($this->createQueryBuilder('b')->getQuery()->getResult()); which should give you all your rows.  Doctrine does support [query filters](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/filters.html).  Got anything like that going on in your code?  Third party stuff perhaps?

Comment: i think the answer is in the table relations

Comment: I've found the solution, i put an id on 2 columns including one in Date, Doctrine do not authorize that, thanks for all